# How to install and finish using maven mvn?

Tags: android

I am trying to install droid fu through git bash. ive done everything success fully. the only problem is when i do "mvn install" it gives me this error "sh.exe : command not found.

I am following the instructions from github droid fu. but this error is stopping me

```
> Step 2: Install the Android JARs to your local Maven repository
```

Droid-Fu must be compiled against the android.jar and maps.jar library files. Since the build is driven by Maven, you must provide these JARs as artifacts to Maven during the compile stage, otherwise the build will fail. We can do this with the maven-android SDK deployer.

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer.git
 $ cd maven-android-sdk-deployer
  $ mvn install

  (requires ANDROID_HOME to point to your SDK home)

    This will install all JAR files from $ANDROID_HOME/platforms and $ANDROID_HOME/add-ons as Maven     artifacts.
```

im stuck where it says mvn install by the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to do this under windows (because of sh.exe). Do you have cygwin installed? try running the command `sh -help` from your command prompt (`start->run->cmd`), do you still get this error?

Comment: It just says sh is not recognized. And no i dont have cygwin installed.

Comment: To run GIT under windows you will require certain tools - either MSysGit, or GIT under CygWin. sh.exe is a GNU Bash shell, usually installed with Cygwin [http://www.cygwin.com/](http://www.cygwin.com/). I can only recommend you to try installing cygwin with git support and see if that helps you. The error you are describing doesn't come from mvn or android directly, but because you are missing the GNU Bash for windows.

Comment: I didnt see git n the package window of cygwin